# Is asList Function Part of Lamdaj library

Tags: java, functional-programming, lambdaj

I'm trying to understand lambdaj library in order to use functional style programming in java. Their wiki page example uses a function called asList which I don't see in any of the lambda packages.

I'm using lambdaj 2.4 version  and I'm referring to https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

Am I missing anything here ? Is it a function that is assumed to be written by the users of the library?

Comment: Most likely [Array.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)() function is in the [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) class.  It acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs.

If you don't want to clutter the code with qualifier references (i.e. "Arrays.") you can import the method via a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`

Comment: I'm aware of this API. Arrays.asList(). I suspect that is not what the wiki example intended. Had that been the case, they should have very well said Arrays.asList instead of the short form. I'm expecting a asList function (static import) just like filter,having,foreach functions

Comment: If want to access it as a static import then you just have to call "import static java.util.Arrays.asList;"  

Additionally the comments on the wiki page reference a requested change of "Arrays.asList instead of asList, this can be confusing to Java newbies"  showing that Arrays.asList(..) is the correct intention.